# How do I take input data and print the input formatted in a pre-coded HTML format

Tags: python, algorithm, input, output

I currently use txt editor to modify my email newsletter code that i send to vendors.

It is tedious, however it does allow for me to create a html table and edit it and send out to customers.

I thought it might be easier to code something that would allow me to type the input and the program would then give me and output of the formatted HTML code ready to copy and paste to my newsletter email service.

this is what i currently have, but it does not print the code with the necessary input values. 
this is what i have so far

```
"""
VAN_REEFER = input("VAN OR REEFER OR POWER ONLY?")
PICKUP_LOCATION = input("WHERE DOES THIS PICKUP?")
PICKUP_TIME = input("WHAT TIME DOES THIS PICKUP?")
DROP_LOCATION = input("WHERE DOES THIS DROP?")
DROP_TIME = input("WHAT TIME DOES THIS DROP?")
ACCEPT_NOW = input("ACCEPT NOW RATE")

print ("""<tr>
<td>(VAN_REEFER)</td>
<td>(PICKUP_LOCATION)<br><b>(PICKUP_TIME)</b></br></td>
<td>(DROP_LOCATION)<br><b>DROP_TIME</b></br></td>
<TD><B>(ACCEPT_NOW)</B></TD>
<td>
<a href="mailto:Dispatch%40MYEMAIL.com?subject=%20%F0%9F%90%A2%20-%20%20-
PICK-
(PICKUP_TIME)
%20-%20-
(PICKUP_LOCATION)
%20
TO
%20-
(DROP_TIME)
-%20
(DROP_LOCATION)
DROP-
%20-%20
(VAN_REEFER)
%0A&amp;body=
I%20HAVE%20A%20TRUCK%20FOR%20THIS%20LOAD-
%20%0A
MY%20RATE%20IS-
%20%0A
THIS%20IS%20MY%20ETA%20TO%20PICKUP%20THIS%20LOAD-
%20%0A
THIS%20IS%20MY%20PHONE%20NUMBER-
%20%0A"><b>BID HERE</b></a>
</td>
</tr>
""")
"""
```

what i would like for this do is to take as many inputs that i want and when i am done it would recreate that code, with the different inputs that were entered by the end user. sometimes there might be 1 or 2 sets of inputs, sometimes there might be a dozen.  once completed the program would compile each input into the code that i need to copy and paste to my email marketing service.

can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [template engines](https://www.fullstackpython.com/template-engines.html) such as [Jinja](https://palletsprojects.com/p/jinja/) or [mako](https://www.makotemplates.org/).

You can write html templates like this (example is from [this Jinja tutorial](https://realpython.com/primer-on-jinja-templating/)):

```
  <p>My string: {{my_string}}</p>
  <p>Value from the list: {{my_list[3]}}</p>
  <p>Loop through the list:</p>
  <ul>
    {% for n in my_list %}
    <li>{{n}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

and the template engine will dynamically replace the variables given in the double curly brackets `{{}}`. You can even create loops and conditions using `{% ... %}`.